# Method prints array elements way off line, and hyphens out of order

Tags: java, arrays, loops, format, output

So I'm trying to print out an arrays contents created from user input (size has to be odd and between 3 and 11), which doubles as the columns and rows of the array. With characters in certain places to make patterns. Everything is fine except for the format. It prints out correctly but not in the right places. The characters are off and hyphens print in the wrong sequence for some reason. They're supposed to be printed before and after the array. The number of hyphens is correct, it's just that I'm supposed to be getting

```
-----------                             
 *    
   *      
     *    
       *  
         *
-----------
```

but instead I get

```
*     
 *   
  *  
   * 
    *
-----------

                       -----------
```

I have no idea why the other hyphen line is so far out, It's almost comedic how off it is. Here is the code

```
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

    int dimension = findDimension();
    char [] [] array2d = new char [dimension] [dimension];

    char star = '*';

    array2d = leftDiagonal(star, dimension);
    print(array2d);
}

public static int findDimension() {
    int dimension = 0;
    Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in); 
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter an odd integer between 3 and 11 please: ");
        dimension = keybd.nextInt();
    } while (dimension%2 == 0);
    return dimension;
}
```

This is where the problem should be as it's the method that does all the printing but not sure. I put the print statements for the hyphens before and after the loop so I'm confused as to why it does this. Also there should be a space before every element is printed, which is why I put " " in the print statement but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
public static void print(char [] [] arrayParam) {
    for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for( int row = 0; row < arrayParam.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < arrayParam.length; column++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arrayParam[row][column]);
        }
    }
    for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
public static char [] [] leftDiagonal(char starParam, int dimenParam) {
    char [] [] leftD = new char [dimenParam] [dimenParam];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimenParam; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < dimenParam; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                System.out.print(starParam);
            } 
            else {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return leftD;
}
```

UPDATE: After taking into account what I've been told I've managed to get the right code. Here it is, thank you all again for the help.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    int dimension = findDimension();
    char [] [] array2d = new char [dimension] [dimension];

    char star = '*';

    array2d = leftDiagonal(star, dimension);
    print(array2d);

    array2d = rightDiagonal(star, dimension);
    System.out.println();
    print(array2d);
}

public static int findDimension() {
    int dimension = 0;
    Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in); 
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter an odd integer between 3 and 11 please: ");
        dimension = keybd.nextInt();
    } while (dimension%2 == 0);
    return dimension;
}

public static void print(char [] [] arrayParam) {
    for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(char[] row : arrayParam)
    {
        for(char c : row)
            System.out.print(" " + c);
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }

    for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}

public static char [] [] leftDiagonal(char starParam, int dimenParam) {
    char [] [] leftD = new char [dimenParam] [dimenParam];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimenParam; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < dimenParam; j++) {
            if (i == j) 
                leftD[i][j] = starParam;
            else 
                leftD[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return leftD;
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to, you can try any code you want ? Or you have to debug this specific code ?

Comment: So long as the format is right I can try any code I want, though so long as I can understand my error in the end is what I want to achieve the most. I  don't get why the output is so off.

Comment: How you are running this code ? you are only filling "left diagonal" and in your expected "output" you have added `*` in all the array ?

Comment: At the moment I'm only running "leftDiagonal" yes. I filled the array in "leftDiagonal" but only for the areas where both the row and column match, the other areas got a blank space. That's how I get the pattern I needed. I'm just unsure why it doesn't print with the right format.

Comment: i am answering it ... got everything working fine

Comment: OP waiting for your response on my answer .... it worked for you ?

Comment: Thank you, I was testing it out on my side and it works fine except for one small part. It prints out with a * in every element position now instead of just the diagonal line It's suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

There was several issues in your code, I have fixed them and mentioned them in code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class PrintShape
 {
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        int dimension = findDimension();
        char [] [] array2d = new char [dimension] [dimension];

        char star = '*';

        array2d = leftDiagonal(star, dimension);
        print(array2d);
    }

    public static int findDimension() 
    {
        int dimension = 0;
        Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in); 
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an odd integer between 3 and 11 please: ");
            dimension = keybd.nextInt();
        } while (dimension%2 == 0);
        return dimension;
    }

    public static void print(char [] [] arrayParam) 
    {
        // i cant understand why are you printing so many hyphen "(arrayParam.length*2)+1"
        // so i left it on you 
        for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++) 
            System.out.print("-");

        System.out.println();
        for(char[] row : arrayParam)
        {
            for(char c : row)
                System.out.print(c);
            System.out.printf("\n ");
        }

        //Problem: 
         // this "-" starts where the array printing end as you are not printing any newline ..
         // it starts printing hyphen on the same line.. that why you get the second row of "-" so far 

         //Fixed:
        System.out.printf("\n");


        for (int hyphen = 0; hyphen < (arrayParam.length*2)+1; hyphen++)  
            System.out.print("-");
    }

    public static char [] [] leftDiagonal(char starParam, int dimenParam) 
    {
        char [] [] leftD = new char [dimenParam] [dimenParam];
        for (int i = 0; i < dimenParam; i++)
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < dimenParam; j++) 
            {
                if (i == j)
                                     {
                    // Probelm : you are just printing the "*"and no saving it in the array 
                    // thats why you are getting only blank spaces in the "print()"
                    System.out.print(starParam);
                                            leftD[i][j] = starParam;
                                      }
                else 
                    System.out.print(' ');
                // soution : save it in the array

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return leftD;
    }
}
```

Do tell me if you find something difficult.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work fine for the most part. I understand I have to save my characters in the array now but it prints out with every element filled with a character now.

Comment: You want only diagonals ?

Comment: first in your `leftDiagonal()` you print left diagoanls ... in `print()` you again want to print only diagonals ?

Comment: Because according to your expected output you should print all array having "*"

Comment: Oh God you're right. Sorry I copy and pasted the wrong output I wanted. I changed it now but yeah I only want the diagonals. I managed to get close to it by having leftD[i][j] = starParam and leftD[i][j] =  '  '  underneath the if and else statements. The only problem now is that the spacing is off.

Comment: Now it prints out the array two times and gives me two different looking arrays.

Comment: I think I can just remove the System.out.print(starParam); and  System.out.print(' '); parts and replace them with leftD[i][j] = starParam; and leftD[i][j] = '   ';   If I do that it only prints out the array once, all that's wrong is it needs to be more to the right.

Comment: No worries, I did. I'm just saying that for some reason it printed out the array 2 times with different looks. Sorry If I confused you.

Comment: Well, if my answer solved your  problem, you can “accept it as answer” ... so that if anyone have same issue in future they can have a handy help without asking a new question.. thats how things work in StackOverflow ... happy coding :)

Comment: I see, that's fine. I have to do things on my own eventually after all. Thank you for the help regardless. It was very informative.